# Let $L|K$ be a field extension and $\alpha \in L$ separable. Why does $\sigma(\mu_{\alpha})$ factor into pairwise different factors in $\bar{L}?$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Here, $\sigma : K \to \bar{L}$ is a ring homomorphism and $\bar{L}$ the algebraic closure of $L$. $\mu_{\alpha}$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

$\sigma(\mu_{\alpha})$ is the polynomial that's created from $\mu_{\alpha}$ by applying $\sigma$ to its coefficients.

Since $\alpha$ is separable, $\mu_{\alpha}$ factors into pairwise different factors in $\bar{L}$ by definition.

Why does then $\sigma(\mu_{\alpha})$ also factor into pairwise different linear factors in $\bar{L}$? Is that because $\sigma$ is injective?

Comment: $\sigma$, being a ring homomorphism defined on a field, is one-to-one, and onto its image. Thus $K\cong\sigma(K)$, via $\sigma$. If there are repeated factors in $\sigma(\mu_\alpha)$, then just apply the inverse of $\sigma$, to get repeated factdors of $\mu_\alpha$.

Comment: @Lubin: Thanks for clearing that up.